# Getting error on making http request to an api using angular

Tags: angular

I'm making an angular web app where I'm making HTTP requests to an API hosted on Firebase to fetch data using post request  but I'm getting the following error when the page loads

```
Failed to load https://chat-f0225.firebaseapp.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access
```

Here is my code

user.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../model/User';
import { Methods } from '../model/Method';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/Observable/of';
import {  HttpClient , HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  tickets:User[];
  method:Methods;
  postUrl = 'https://chat-f0225.firebaseapp.com'
  data:Observable<any>;
  httpOptions = {
    headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getTickets(method:Methods):Observable<User[]>
  {
    return this.http.post<User[]>(this.postUrl,method,this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

User.component.ts

```js
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { User} from '../../model/User';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import { Methods } from '../../model/Method';
@Component({
    selector : 'app-user',
   templateUrl : './user.component.html',
   styleUrls : ['./user.component.css'],
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit{
    //Properties
    tickets : User[];
    method:Methods;

    constructor(private userService: UserService)
    {
    }
    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.method={name:"FetchTickets",userId:"dke1kor"};
        console.log("here");

        this.userService.getTickets(this.method as Methods).subscribe(ticket =>{
            console.log(ticket);

        })
    }
}
```

How do I access that API?

Comment: method is your post data? then what is data?

Comment: what data?I'm passing method to that function which will be the post data

Comment: why are you trying to fetch data from http.post? if you want to fetch data from server so you have to use http.get method

Comment: Because that api demands so...It will return back the data for that user and then also add that user to that database

Answer (score 1):

You run into an issue with CORS.
CORS has to be handled properly at **server-side**. The Server must send an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' where the accessing hosts are whitelisted or * for all Hosts.

see https://enable-cors.org/ for further details.